# What am I missing? Set font color javascript

Tags: javascript

```
function f2color1(Fahr) {
  var Fahr;
  if (Fahr >= 80) {
    console.log(Fahr.fontcolor("red"));
  } else if (Fahr <= 40) {
    console.log(Fahr.fontcolor("blue"));
  }
}

f2color1(30);
```

This is what I've written so far.  I get the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'color' of undefined
>
> at f2color2 (script.js:34)
>
> at script.js:38

Comment: What is Fahr???

Comment: Why is `Fahr` both an argument *and* a variable? It's usually one or the other, not both. By declaring `var Fahr` you're creating an undefined variable. Additionally `30` does not have a `fontcolor` function, it's just a number.

Comment: @tadman, adding the `var` in the middle doesn't create an undefined variable in the middle of the block (as this can be an interpretation of your statement). Javascript just [hoists it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var#var_hoisting) to the top as an undeclared variable, allowing it to be defined by the parameter when present.

Comment: @SunnyPatel That's true to a degree, but `Fahr` is being populated with a number in this code and yet it shows up as "undefined".

Comment: I tested the code, and it is as intended where if we run what he posted, the error would be `Uncaught TypeError: Fahr.fontColor is not a function`. Though he is reporting the error through another function "`f2color2` (script.js:34)".

Answer (score 1):

You were probably going for this, assuming that `Fahr` is a number.

```
function f2color1(Fahr) {
  if (Fahr >= 80) {
    console.log('%c' + Fahr, 'color: red');
  } else if (Fahr <= 40) {
    console.log('%c' + Fahr, 'color: blue');
  }
}

f2color1(30);
```

`Fahr` is already defined as a parameter, so `var Fahr` is unnecessary.

Comment: This code works, but seems more advanced then what we are learning at the moment, what does %c do in javascript?

Comment: `%c` acts like a way to configure the CSS style of the text following it. The next argument in the `console.log` is the actual style. You can see the details here from [MDN console](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console#Usage). This is specific to the console object.

Answer (score 0):

Fahr is a variable you created which you are using as an integer, integers do not have an attribute called fontColor, so you will need to recreate the function with a string or change Fahr to a string so you can change font color

Somethig like this code work, I have used Fahr as a integer for the if statement and then converted it to a string:

```js
function f2color1(Fahr) {
  if (Fahr >= 80) {
    console.log(String(Fahr).fontcolor("red"));
  } else if (Fahr <= 40) {
    console.log(String(Fahr).fontcolor("blue"));
  }
}

f2color1(30);
```

Comment: Are you sure the output is supposed to read `<font color="blue">String</font>` or `<font color="red">String</font>`?

Comment: He has it writing to the console, so I just left that line in, but ultimately, that will change the font color. He can alter the code accordingly

Comment: Then give him a little something better to start with? Perhaps `var str = Fahr.toString();`

Comment: This code when converting to string is giving an output of: <font color="blue">30</font>

Comment: Clearly he wants that, because he wanted to use the dot notation, in a web environment, it will be interpreted as just the value in the desired color